# How should I configure redirects for multisite Codeigniter app?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have multiple codeigniter sites setup like so:

1. /CI_Site1
2. /CI_site1/CI_Site2
3. /CI_site1/CI_Site3

Right now to use my the second and and third site I have to do it like so:

*mydomain.com/CI_Site2/index.php/controller/function*

If I don't put the index.php then it throws up a 404 in the root site(AKA CI_Site1).

How should I configure htaccess or apache site conf or CI config files such that I don't have to add index.php?

I think the first step should be to configure the routes in CI_site1 to not process requests for the other 2 but I don't know how. Here is hoping a Codeigniter pro can help me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I know how to remove index.php from URLs with htaccess. But that is not the issue here. How do I prevent CI_site1 from processing requests that are for CI_site2 and CI_site3?

Comment: Check it https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Thanks but that doesn't help me. It tells me nothing about multisite setups.

Comment: i don't even understand your question - you have one domain - but multiple sites ?

Comment: @sintakonte multiple CI projects in subfolders. domain.com,domain.com/site1,domain.com/site2 are 3 different CI projects. NVM, my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that no extra configuration was required. It is sufficient to use .htaccess to remove index.php. My issue was that apache was blocking .htaccess files in its default configuration. Editing apache2.conf to allow processing of htaccess files resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code in file and save it as .htaccess then upload it to Project folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Make sure your server mod_rewrite is on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using routes?

```
$route['CI_Site1'] = '/CI_Site1';
$route['CI_Site2'] = '/CI_site1/CI_Site2';
$route['CI_Site3'] = '/CI_site1/CI_Site3';
```